# e.preventDefault() - issues with applying it to all but one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I've read quite a few things on stack related to this issue, but I can't seem to solve my problem.

Essentially, I'm using jQueryModal (http://jquerymodal.com/).

What I want to have happen is, when the modal is launched, aka:

```
$(".buttonSpacing").click(function() {
    $("#page").modal();
}
```

the modal opens up as expected. Contained in a div in that modal is a contenteditable div. Basically, I want to prevent default on everything except the contenteditable div. When the modal closes, I want events to then be unbound.

Something like this:

```
$(".buttonSpacing").click(function() {
    $("#page").modal();

    $(':not(#myContentEditableDiv)').bind('mousedown',function(e)
    {
        e.stopPropagation(); // Tried with and without this line
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

doesn't seem to work. #myContentEditableDiv loses the default functionality as well as everything else.

If a previous question has answered this, I guess I wasn't able to apply it correctly to my situation.

The reason for this is I want the cursor to always remain in the editable area, wherever it is they left it, even when I'm having them select things to dynamically add to the editable area, or if they accidentally click outside of it.

Given my situation, how can I make this happen?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Here's a js fiddle showing the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/7Lwudpr4/2/

Comment: code on jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: @marzelin put a js fiddle example in there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the mouse down event is propagating from the text area to the parent elements, which are then preventing the default action. To fix this issue, add the following:

```
$('#textArea').bind('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gp43028d/1/

Note that you'll probably need to handle the mouseup events on your other elements, as they won't fire click events since preventDefault() is called on the mousedown event.